# Why change on AsyncLocal are not being reflected on Main method ( C# )

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

Why when calling Test() changes to `data.Value` are not being reflected to the Main method? even though there is no `await` on the Test method which means it will be executed synchronously.

```
public class Data {
    public Data data;
    public int count;   
}

public class Program {
    public static AsyncLocal<Data> data = new();
    
    public static async Task Main(string[] args){
        data.Value = new Data{
            data = new Data{ count = 5 },
            count = 10
        };
        
        Console.WriteLine($"[Main] - Data = {data?.Value?.GetHashCode()}, Data Count = {data?.Value?.count}, " +
                          $"SubData Count = {data?.Value?.data?.count},\n ThreadId = {Thread.CurrentThread.ExecutionContext!.GetHashCode()}");           
        Console.WriteLine($"[Main] - AsyncLocal HashCode = {data.GetHashCode()}");
        
        var task = Test();
        
        Console.WriteLine($"[Main] - Data = {data?.Value?.GetHashCode()}, Data Count = {data?.Value?.count}, " +
                          $"SubData Count = {data?.Value?.data?.count},\n ThreadId = {Thread.CurrentThread.ExecutionContext.GetHashCode()}");                   
        Console.WriteLine($"[Main] - AsyncLocal HashCode = {data.GetHashCode()}");

        await task;
    }
    
    private static async Task Test()
    {
        data.Value = new Data{
            data = new Data{ count = 15 },
            count = 20
        };
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Data = {data.GetHashCode()}, Data Count = {data?.Value?.count}, SubData Count = {data?.Value?.data?.count}, " +
                          $"\n ThreadId = {Thread.CurrentThread.ExecutionContext.GetHashCode()}");  
        
        Console.WriteLine($"AsyncLocal HashCode = {data.GetHashCode()}");
    }
}
```

> [Main] - Data = 58225482, Data Count = 10, SubData Count = 5,
> ThreadId = 54267293
> [Main] - AsyncLocal HashCode = 18643596

> Data = 18643596, Data Count = 20, SubData Count = 15,
> ThreadId = 33574638
> AsyncLocal HashCode = 18643596

> [Main] - Data = 58225482, Data Count = 10, SubData Count = 5,
> ThreadId = 54267293
> [Main] - AsyncLocal HashCode = 18643596

Comment: It’s an async declared method. It’s been rewritten

Comment: It's not at all clear what you expected to happen here since you keep completely replacing the value of `data` with no attempt to take any value based on its current value

Comment: Also not having "await" before asynchronous method call it doesn't mean it will run synchronously. In that way, your method Test(); is returning Task object that holds reference to the thread that this method is running. You can await it later in case of need.

Comment: @DanielA.White that's true, but still, the code seems to be executed synchronously if you check it in sharplab.io

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm just trying to understand what is happing behind the scenes here, because if we make Test method void non-async the change will be reflected.

Comment: @AdamOramus Since the Test method contains no await keyword on it, I think it will run synchronously. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async

An async method runs synchronously until it reaches its first await expression, at which point the method is suspended until the awaited task is complete. In the meantime, control returns to the caller of the method, as the example in the next section shows.

Comment: Check https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-async-await-really-works/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why when calling Test() changes to data.Value are not being reflected to the Main method?

Each `async` method gets a *copy* of the execution context, which includes `AsyncLocal<T>` values. In other words, `AsyncLocal<T>` values do not flow "up".

Technically, they can flow "up" from non-`async` methods, but I strongly recommend not depending on that behavior; it's strange and can easily break if any intermediate method changes from sync to async.

> even though there is no await on the Test method which means it will be executed synchronously.

The `async` keyword (or technically, the state machine generated by the `async` keyword) is what captures the context.

`Test` does execute synchronously, since there's no `await`; but there was a copy made due to the `async` keyword. Since the modification only happened to the copy, it's lost anyway, even though `Test` executed synchronously.

Comment: So technically state machine will change execution context of the current thread and return back to the old one when returned from the Test method call, is it possible for me to achive the same behaviour without the state machine (i.e Test method being void non async). Thanks for clarification.